# How to get file contents of old site on drupal?

Tags: html, drupal

We have a site running to drupal and migrated it to Squarespace. I have to retrieve some pages of drupal site but I can no longer view the site. Do you know any way to get the old content of website on drupal? Please know that we still have access to the drupal box. Any suggestions will be a big help.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to make the old Drupal site available again through the browser running on a different domain like `old.example.com`, login into the admin panel and start copy/pasting content.

If you know your way around your computer, know the IP address the old server is running on you could for the time being change the host file of your machine to send requests for your site to the old server and get access to the site that way.

Migrating content by automating the process is also an option, but it is not only time consuming, it requires in depth knowledge of both platforms so is mostly a very expensive solution if you are not able to do this yourself.

But if I read your question, I think the first option is the easiest option. Get a hold of the technical person/party of the server the site is running on and get them to make the site accessible on a different domain.